# Google Apps Script: getUsers = not producing the full list

Tags: google-apps-script

Issue Description: 
Want to getUsers of a group and put the list in a file.  Only part of the list is being written.

Reproducing Issue:
Using two Google examples combined to (1) get a comma-delimited list of email addresses subscribed to a Group and (2) write the list to a Google Docs file and then email that to self:

```
// Part (1)... 
function listGroupMembers() {
  var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail("particular.group@example.com");
  var s = group.getEmail() + ': ';
  var users = group.getUsers();
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    s = s + user.getEmail() + ", ";
  }

// Part (2)... 
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(group.getEmail() + ' Member List');
  doc.appendParagraph('This is the list of emails on the ' + group.getEmail() + ' Email Reflector: ');
  doc.appendParagraph(s);
  doc.saveAndClose();

  var url = doc.getUrl();

  var emailAddress = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,
                     'Member List for ' + group.getEmail(),
                     'Here is a link to a document ccontaining the list of all emails in the ' + group.getEmail() + ' Email Reflector... ' + url);
}
```

Failing Result: 
The resulting file is produced and contains 8 email addresses.  It should contain 27 addresses (the full group).  I cannot see what is preventing the whole list from being created.  Of the 8 people, some people are in my domain, some not.  Some other domains are hosted with Google, some not.  Some emails have "nicknames" some not.

Thanks, 
JJR

Answer (score 0):

The GroupsApp returns users, which are email addresses that correspond to an actual Google account. Mailing lists and unknown email addresses are not returned. See [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1157) for more details.